# Tomcat7 + Eclipse deletes source code in `work` folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, development-environment

It is third time, when our company struggles strange behavior of Eclipse, working with Tomcat7 project. After some unknown actions (mine last were "Change context name" and "Export to .war file") it **deletes content** of `work` folder, that is all source code.

Sure this is unexpectable. What are possible solutions to prevent this?

We are using Eclipse Juno 1.5.0.20120614-1633 and tomcat7

EDIT:
Our project is not under $CATALINA_HOME/work, but an external folder. Then we have this in the `E:\WebServers\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\my_project.xml`

`<Context path="/my_project" reloadable="true" docBase="E:\_Projects\my_project" workDir="E:\_Projects\my_project\work" />`

Comment: Why do you have your source code in Tomcat's work directory?

Comment: What is correct place for source code then?

Comment: @MartinWilson it is not under $CATALINA_HOME/work, but an external folder
Then we have this in the `E:\WebServers\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\my_project.xml`

`<Context path="/my_project" reloadable="true" docBase="E:\_Projects\my_project" workDir="E:\_Projects\my_project\work" />`

Comment: By specifying workDir as "E:\_Projects\my_project\work" you are telling Tomcat to use this directory as its work directory for this webapp. Tomcat's work directory is where it stores compiled JSPs etc - it's not a directory you should use.

Comment: @MartinWilson got it, thanks! Though, I don't understand under what conditions does tomcat clear this folder. During 1.5-year development it was done only three times.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reprodicible way to do that with my current setup.

1. Make sure an option "Can update context definition" is enabled, and "reloadable" is true.
2. Run tomcat server
3. Rename context name and wait while tomcat reloads
4. Rename context name back and wait while tomcat reloads

Your "workDir" directory is now cleared.